# How to display items from checkbox list using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the value of some checkbox which is selected using ajax and jquery. Right now I have all items listed on my site, but I want to let user to check the checkbox to get the selected items.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet] public JsonResult getCategoryItems(){}
```

How can it be done?

View:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.CarsCount.Count(); i++)
{                
    var cars = Model.CarsCount.ElementAt(i);              
    <span class="label label-info">
        @cars.CategoryName <span class="badge">@cars.CategoryCount</span
    </span>
    @Html.CheckBox(cars.CategoryName, cars.isChecked, new { id = "carsCheckbox"})
}
```

As you can see, the code above is just counting the items in category to list as checkbox. I just want to let a user to check the checkboxes, however so user can get the items by check an item from checkboxes.

```
private IEnumerable<CarViewModel> GetListOfCars()
    {
        var listOfcars = this.Data.cars.All()
            .Select(t => new CarViewModel
            {
                Id = t.Id,
                Title = t.Title,
                Price = t.Price ,
                FileName = t.FileName
            });
        return listOfcars;
    }
```

Comment: Show your view including any scripts

Comment: @StephenMuecke please see my post for more info. Thanks.

Comment: You use of `CheckBox()` is generating duplicate `name` attributes with no relationship to your model and duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html. I cannot understand what your trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well. What I really mean, is how can I get for example check the checkboxes to get the data? Could you give me some idea to how to do it? forget the code that I mentioned. Thanks

Comment: So are you wanting to post the values of the checked checkboxes back to the `getCategoryItems()` using ajax and return some data?

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's right! Also see the code mentioned in the post. The code is getting all cars. And how can i use ajax and return some data using checkbox by checking them?

Comment: It not clear how your `GetListOfCars()` method relates to what your wanting to do. What is the model in the view? You need to give each checkbox a value (I assume the `Id` of the car?) and then use jquery to build an array if the `Id` values which you can then post to the method with a parameter which is `IEnumerable<int>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing. But i am assuming when user select a checkbox, you want to send the Id of that checkbox to your action method and get some response back which you will use for updating your UI.

As Stephen Muecke mentioned in the comments, Your current code is generating duplicate Id values for the checkboxes. You should not have duplicate ids for your form elements.

Assuming your each item in your `HesViewModel` has an `Id` property (with unique values) which we will use to send to the server.

When you render the checkBox, you might pass in the html attributes for rendering **css class** (We will use for our jQuery selection to listen to any changes to the checkbox's state) and an **Id** ( we will use this unique value to send to server)

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.HesViewModels.Count(); i++)
{
    var cars = Model.HesViewModels.ElementAt(i);
    <span class="label label-info"> @cars.DetailRasonCode </span>

    @Html.CheckBox(cars.CategoryName,
               cars.isChecked, new { @class = "myCheck", id = cars.Id})
}
```

Now we will have some jQuery code to listen to changes in the checkboxes. When it is checked, We will use the Id attribute value and send it to server using ajax.

```
$(function () {

    $("input.myCheck").change(function(e) {
        var _this = $(this);
        if (_this.is(":checked")) {
            var id = _this.attr("id");
            alert(id);
            //Let's make the Ajax call now
            var url = "@Url.Action("getCategoryItems","Home")?id=" + id;
            $.get(url, function () {

            }).done(function (res) {
                alert('response from server received');
                console.log(res);
                //Use the response as needed to update your UI
            }).fail(function () {
                alert("error");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Ofcourse now your action method should accept an id as parameter

```
[HttpGet] 
public JsonResult getCategoryItems(int id)
{
   // to do : Send some useful data back.
   return Json(new { Data :"Good"},JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Yes, my HesViewModel has an Id property which is CategoryId. So i'm using @Html.CheckBox(cars.CategoryName,cars.isChecked, new { @class = "myCheck", id = cars.CategoryId + i}) Now I have to find out how I can display current item when checked. Thanks anyway!